# Error inserting to database in Android/phpMyAdmin

Tags: android, sql, phpmyadmin

If I test my PHP file in a web browser, it works (e.g.  given `newObsindiaries.php?idd="52"&ido="1"&when="10"`, it inserts into the database without any problems).

In Android, however, it doesn't work and returns this message in the log:

> org.json.JSONException: Unterminated array at character 5 of [idd=52, ido=1, when=10]

This is the PHP code:

```
<?php
$dbhost = "127.0.0.1";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";
$dbname = "clinic_last";

$link = @mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname)
    or die("Impossibile collegarsi al server: " . mysqli_error());
mysqli_select_db($link ,'clinic_last')
    or die("unable to select database 'dbname': " . mysqli_error());

$idd = $_GET['idd'];
$ido = $_GET['ido'];        
$when = $_GET['when'];

$string = ("INSERT INTO obsindiaries (`when`, ido, idd)
    SELECT $when,$ido,idd FROM diaries WHERE idd = $idd LIMIT 1");

$string2 = "INSERT INTO obsindiaries (idod,idd,ido,`when`) VALUES
    (NULL,'$idd','$ido','$when')";

$flag['code']=0;

$result = mysqli_query($link,$string);
// check if row inserted or not
if ($result) {
    // successfully inserted into database    
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "**successfully Registration.**";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} 
if (!$result) {
    // failed to insert row
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}

if (!$result) {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
mysqli_close($link);  
?>
```

This is part of file `.class`:

```
public void ClickSaveObsindiaries(){
    SavingObs=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.saveObsindiaries);
    SavingObs.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //INSERISCO VALORI DENTRO LISTA
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("idd", ID_diary.getText().toString()));
            int positionTypeObs = typeObsindiaries.getSelectedItemPosition() + 1;
            String valueType = String.valueOf(positionTypeObs);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ido",valueType));
            char first = hours.getSelectedItem().toString().charAt(0);
            if (first=='I')
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("when", IntervalHours.getText().toString()));
            else 
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("when", hours.getSelectedItem().toString()));

            System.out.println("valore di RESULT: "+nameValuePairs.toString());
            try {
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/newObsindiaries.php");
                Log.e("httpPost is:"," "+httpPost.toString());
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));//,"UTF-8"

                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();
                Log.e("pass 1", "connection success ");
            } catch(Exception e) {  
                Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid IP Address", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } 
            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                result = sb.toString();
                Log.e("pass 2", "connection success ");
            } catch(Exception e) {
                Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
            }     
            try {
                JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(nameValuePairs.toString());
                code=(json_data.getInt("code"));

                if(code==1) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Inserted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sorry, Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch(Exception e) {
                Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
                Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(add_obsindiaries.this, R.style.myDialog));
            builder.setMessage("Misurazione inserita! Premere OK per tornare alla lista delle misurazioni")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    Intent listOBS = new Intent(add_obsindiaries.this,obsindiaries_list.class);
                    fromObsList.putString("idDiary", fromObsList.getString("idDiary"));
                    listOBS.putExtras(fromObsList);
                    add_obsindiaries.this.finish();
                    startActivity(listOBS);
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is from this line

```
JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(nameValuePairs.toString());
```

You are trying to parse data return from your param. It doesn't make sense. And `nameValuePairs.toString()` will return the string that doesn't match with Json format, that is why you got the error. You should use `result` instead of `nameValuePairs.toString()`

```
JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
```

Comment: thanks for reply, but it doesn't work yet. Log show me 'new' error 
"org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject"
i don't understand, i use this method to insert into database in two other activity , only in this doesn't work.

Comment: You need to check the return Json from your server. Try to use some tool like Postman for get exactly result with your request. Can you post the function `json_encode` in your php project.

Comment: I don't know where is the problem. i check it using postman, ecc ; if pass parameter in browser php file work, else no, there is a problem with  structure of format when pass to php file, i don't know really need to help

Comment: Can you post to here your output you get when you use your browser?

Comment: this is  the output 
{"success":0,"message":"Oops! An error occurred."}{"success":0,"message":"Required field(s) is missing"}

Comment: Can you send me the page source? In your output page, if you use Chrome choose View -> Developer -> View Source.

Comment: add page source , i added it as answer down this comment. thanks

Comment: Your output is not in json format. Using this tool http://jsonlint.com/ for checking your json.

You can only return  `{"success":0,"message":"Oops! An error occurred."}`. It's enough.